# How to read arrays from user in java?

Tags: java

What is the **java** equivalent of the following C code.

`for(i = 0;i<n;i++)

scanf("%d",&a[i])`

where `i` is a previously defined integer and `a` is an array

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The scanner class is used, `System.in` is the standard input, but it can get other input streams:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
for(i = 0;i<n;i++) {
    a[i] = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Anyway, this might cause you some problems if the user press enter between two numbers, so another approach will be:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
for(i = 0;i<n;i++) {
    String token = scan.next();
    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(token);
}
```